# getElementById from ancestor element to remove child's class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to use a parent element with getElementById.

For example: I want to use ancestor id "test" to remove class "myClass".

HTML

```
<div id="test">
  <div id="test-child-one">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="test-child-two">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="test-child-three">
    <div class="myClass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 var element = document.getElementById("test");
 element.className = element.className.replace(/\bmyClass\b/g, "");
```

It won't work. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to get the ancestor? are there other divs with class myClass??

Comment: Are you looking to remove the class `myClass` from any child element of `#test` that has the class `myClass`? Or are you looking to specifically remove `myClass` in this example?

Comment: But: `document.querySelector('#test .myClass').classList.remove('myClass')`? You need to explain why you want to so far up the ancestry tree to do this (whether you *do* want to do this or whether you think this is for some reason the only or best way to do what you want); because it's horribly over-complicated as a solution to the problem you're describing.

Comment: You select an element and you remove the class from that element. The element does not have that class. You should be selecting the element with that class to remove it.

Comment: @RyanWilson, Others have variable id, but the top id has only fixed id. So, I want to get it without knowing variable id. Because I don't know how to handle variable id. There is only one class name 'myClass' in the tree.

Comment: @DavidThomas, the tree is involved a repeatable field so, the id has a variable name such as id-0-0, id-0-1, id-0-2 and go on except the ancestor id.

Comment: @Peter, any child element of '#test.

Comment: Danny, that seems to mean - if I'm understanding you properly - that `document.querySelectorAll('#test .myClass')` would still work?

Comment: @DavidThomas,         `var element = document.querySelectorAll('#test .myClass');
        element.className = element.className.replace(/\bmyClass\b/g, "");` doesn't work, but the following snippet works. `const childEles = document.querySelectorAll('#test .myClass');
for(let x = 0; x < childEles.length; x++){
    childEles[x].classList.remove("myClass");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
//If you want to remove the class from all decendants
//Get all decendants with class "myClass"
const childEles = document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('.myClass');



//Or per David
const childEles = document.querySelectorAll('#test .myClass');

//Iterate the collection and remove "myClass" from all decendants
for(let x = 0; x < childEles.length; x++){
    childEles[x].classList.remove("myClass");
}

//If you only want to remove the first decendant
document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('.myClass')[0].classList.remove("myClass");



 //Or per David
 document.querySelectorAll('#test .myClass')[0].classList.remove("myClass);
```

Comment: Why use `getElementById()` at all, when you could easily use: `querySelectorAll('#test .myClass')` which would return the same elements?

Comment: Why not use `getElementById()`? Is using `querySelectorAll('#test .myClass')` faster?

Comment: @DavidThomas OP specified in question "I want to use a parent element with getElementById.", thus the question was about relative access to children of some element that was fetched exactly with getElementById.

Comment: I've never done a performance check, but it seems odd to use two methods to refine the collection when you could use just one.

Comment: @DavidThomas I see your point David, I would be curious to see if one performs better than another, but as the querySelectorAll is taking in params of id test find all elements with class myClass I would wager it is doing the same thing under the hood, evaluate which element has id test first then get all decendants with class myClass. Updated my answer to reflect your suggestion

Comment: @RyanWilson, It works like a charm. Thanks. They both working well. Could I know the difference your coding and the metamaker's coding?

Comment: @Danny metamaker is using some short hand code to do the same thing as what I provided, it is considered by some to be more elegant since it uses less lines of code, but it also takes a better understanding of syntax to read it. Also metamaker is making use of `.forEach()` instead of regular for loops and fat arrow functions in their second example

Comment: @RyanWilson, Sound great! If I want to add a class `yourClass` next to `myClass` when `myClass` exists. Did i miss something? I used this code, but no luck.         `var element, name, arr;
        element = document.getElementById("test").querySelectorAll('myClass');
        name = "yourClass";
        arr = element.className.split(" ");
        if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + name;
        }`

Comment: @Danny When using `.querySelectorAll()` and searching for items by className you have to place a `.` in front of the className like `('.myClass')` and you don't need to append string values in .className just use the .classList.add("yourClass"), so your code would be `const eles = document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('myClass'); for(let x = 0; x < eles.length; x++){ eles[x].classList.add("yourClass"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Do like Ryan Wilson specified it or simple one-liner:

```
document.getElementById("test").querySelectorAll('.myClass').forEach(function (el) { el.classList.remove("myClass"); });
```

Or a beautiful way, if you have transpiler between your code and browser:

```
removeChildrenClass = (parentId, childClass) => document.querySelectorAll(`#${parentId} .${childClass}`).forEach(el => el.classList.remove(childClass));
removeChildrenClass("test", "myClass");
```

Comment: If we're going for one-liners: `forEach( el => el.classList.remove('myClass') );` but remember that one-liners, while they can be beautiful, do sometimes require a greater understanding and explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @DavidThomas arrow syntax is not supported by IE11 (https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions). The method specified in answer will work for all major browsers without Babel/other transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the other answers provided, it seems as though you are looking for [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Given that you already have some ancestor element `element`, querySelectorAll can be used to find all children with the specified class. To build on your example:

**Using querySelectorAll**

```js
// Example constant element IDs/classes
var parentId = "test";
var targetClass = "myClass";

// The given parent element
var element = document.getElementById(parentId);

// Iterate over all children `elem`s with the target class
element.querySelectorAll(targetClass).forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.classList.remove(targetClass);
});
```

This is just an example to demonstrate how querySelectorAll can be used on specific elements to solve exactly such a problem. Note that querySelectorAll will match multiple classes containing `myClass` if they exist, if you want to specifically remove the first such class, you might use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead.